# Видимость переменных

Tags: javascript

Как объявить глобальную переменную из функции, так чтобы её можно было использовать скриптом, который находится в другом файле, пробовал так

```
window.i = "значение переменной";
```

Переменная является глобальной, но почему-то с ней нельзя работать из другого файла со скриптом.

Comment: Покажите пример... Если вы эту функцию вызвали, то в другой она будет видна, даже если подключается файлом.

Comment: а вот на счёт скрипта в котором хотелось бы работать с переменной, он не подключён изначально, подключается он динамически

Answer (score 1):

Файлы в javascript подключаются асинхронно и иногда нельзя с уверенностью сказать, код какого файла будет выполнен раньше. Чтобы убедиться в том, что переменная инициализировалась, можно обернуть её использование как-нибудь так:

```
function checkVariable() {
  if(typeof window.i === 'undefined'){
    setTimeout('checkVariable()', 1000);
  } else {
    console.log('О, появилась:' + window.i);
    // можно её юзать
  }
}
```

Ну и не могу не отметить, что нужно сто раз подумать, прежде чем использовать глобальные переменные. Может, лучше передать данные через DOM с помощью скрытых тегов:

```
<input id="window-i" type="hidden" value="значение переменной">
```

Проблему асинхронности это, однако, всё равно не решит.

Answer (score 0):

Дело скорее всего в том, что в браузере порядок выполнения скриптов может быть любым. При проектировании надо учитывать асинхронную природу Javascript. Чтобы проверить это - попробуйте обернуть `console.log(window.i)` в `setTimeout`.

Совершенно точно - все загруженные файлы будут иметь доступ к общему window (если конено код в них не обёрнут в кложуру вроде `(function (window) { ... })({});` )

Answer (score -1):

При такой записи *window.i = "значение переменной";* у вас вообще должна ошибка вылетать.
В одном файле объявляете переменную глобально *var i = 10;*, т.е. не внутри функции, делаете с ней что хотите, а во втором файле вызываете *alert(window.i);*

Comment: мне надо именно из функции и запись window.i = "значение переменной"; прекрасно выполняется. переменная глобальная даже из функции

Comment: но вот работать с переменной получается только в пределах одного файла

Comment: Да ну объявите переменную до функции! Что тут не понятного?

Comment: Никакой ошибки так не должно вылетать)

Comment: значение переменной зависит от функции, переменная должна быть внутри её

Answer (score -1):

В вашем случае стоит работать с объектом типа hidden и ему присваивать значение. Другим сценарием просто вытаскиваете это значение

> <input type="text" id="hid1" value="">
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> document.getElementById('hid1').value = "1"
> </script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> var number = document.getElementById('hid1').value 
> </script>